# gfx-rs/wgpu wgsl examples uses @ instead of [[]]

Tags: rust, wgpu-rs, wgsl

I have been learning wgpu over the past few days and I have one point of confusion.
When I browse athe wgpu examples (https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu/tree/master/wgpu/examples) they use this syntax for their shaders:

```
struct VertexOutput {
    @location(0)       color:    vec4<f32>,
    @builtin(position) position: vec4<f32>,
}
```

but I have to write my shaders like this:

```
struct VertexOutput {
    [[location(0)]]       color:    vec4<f32>;
    [[builtin(position)]] position: vec4<f32>;
};
```

I much prefer the `@` syntax to the `[[]]` syntax. My guess is that it is a feature I need to enable in my Cargo.toml but I have not been able to find out what feature this is. So if someone could tell me how to use the `@` syntax in my wgsl shaders it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you currently use [`wgpu`](https://crates.io/crates/wgpu/0.12.0) version `0.12.0` from [crates.io](https://crates.io/)?

The `@` syntax is the new updated syntax from the [`webgpu` spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webgpu/). The latest released version of `wgpu` however still uses the old syntax.

If you want to use the new syntax now, you can use the `master` branch from git like so (in your `Cargo.toml`):

```
wgpu = { git = "https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu" }
```

## Update

`wgpu` version `0.13` was released in the meantime, so you can now use

```
wgpu = "0.13"
```

to get the new wgsl syntax.